# How to create a "not pre-release" library in PyPiCloud?

Tags: pypi, python-packaging, twine

Currently, after building a library and use `twine upload dist/*` to publish it to PypiCloud, a pre-release version will be created. When I install it using `pip`, I will have to add `--pre` tag. How can I publish a "not pre-release" version instead?

Comment: Need to use a version string that is not considered as "pre-release". What version string does your library have right now? See [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#pre-releases) for details about the standard for version string formats and their meaning.

Comment: Oh I realized that I couldn't use the library because it is not PEP 440 compliant